# GIT - GitHub Repository Setup Viable?

Tags: git, github

I have a small team of developers and we have purchased a small private repository account. Essentially all we want to do is have this central repository store all of our source code and for each individual developer be able to push and pull to and from that repository as necessary. My understanding of how this works is that each each developer push and pulls to the CLONE URL of the repository (for example: git@github.com:SmallDevTeam/SourceCode). Along with this I am under the impression that each individual developer must have a separate GitHub account and that GitHub identifies each individual developer's commits via their SSH key. Currently, the central repository is set up but contains no SSH Keys. Two of the developers have set up their individual accounts also and have stored their SSH Keys on their accounts.

However, when each developer commits to the remote repository using TortoiseGit, there is no clear evidence of who has committed what aside from the news feed (which is useless as time passes by). I expected to have some sort of log of who the author of each commit was, however GitHub just states that the Author is the central repository (For Example: The repository is set up at git@github.com:SmallDevTeam/SourceCode, therefore the Author is stated as being [SmallDevTeam]). Am I missing something? Surely this should be the developers account name instead?

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

The primary repo would be under the SmallDevTeam account, and that account would add each developer's account as a 'private contributor'.

Check out Episode 1 of the "Insider Guide to GitHub". It explains how to set this up at about the 24:30 mark:

http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-scgithub/insider-guide-to-github